# GridView is not populating from DataBinding mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview

Hi I am trying to load table from MySQL database and show contents of table in a asp:GridView component.

In .aspx file is where my GridView Component is.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ViewUsers" runat="server" 
onselectedindexchanged="ViewUsers_SelectedIndexChanged"  > 
</asp:GridView>
```

In .aspx.cs file is where I have my C# code to Bind the data from MySQL table to the GridView. But for some reason its not doing it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

public partial class viewAdmin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=logintable;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=;";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if ((String)Session["authorize"] != "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM logindata;", conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dataTable);


        ViewUsers.DataSource = dataTable;
        ViewUsers.DataMember = dataTable.TableName;
}

}
```

The GridView Is suppose to be populated when my page is loaded. Any help is greatly appreciated. Oh and Im also a beginner in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `DataBind()` on the GridView.

```
ViewUsers.DataSource = dataTable;
ViewUsers.DataBind();
```

Also, make sure you close that database connection!

Comment: oh Wow. So simple yet so rewarding. Thank you sir.